# Help with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a user submits without any boxes checked. I need my ODM (Mongoid) to update the record appropriately.

Having a bit of trouble with:

```
  <% Notification.all.each do |notification| %>
    <li>
      <%= check_box_tag 'user[notification_ids][]', notification.id, @user.notifications.include?(notification) %>
      <%= label_tag notification.description %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

The [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) suggests that the check_box helper puts in a hidden input. The hidden field has the same name and its attributes mimic an unchecked check box. However, with the above code. I am going through a loop. Which is slightly different.

I tried:

```
<%= check_box('user_notification_ids_', '', options = {:index => notification.id, :checked => @user.notifications.include?(notification)}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0") %>
```

But whenever I submit, I get: ***illegal ObjectId format***

Or should I create the hidden tag for notification_ids manually? Something like:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user[notification_ids][]', '[]' %>
```

Looking to hear your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the first loop you included. It looks much simpler and looks like it does the same thing.

If I understand your first sentence correctly, it sounds like you aren't seeing the user's notifications getting updated to none when they uncheck all the check boxes. When there are no check boxes checked, the browser won't send that param back. It simply won't be included in `params` so when you do something like:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

... notifications won't get updated. In your controller, do this to ensure there is something set for `params[:user][:notifications]`:

```
params[:user][:notifications] ||= []
```

This is will set it to an empty array if there if it doesn't exists and/or there's no value there. This ensures that `update_attributes` will set it to none/empty.

Comment: Yea thats how I currently have it set up. The problem is when the user doesnt select any boxes. Nothing is submitted with the form. In my controller, I could have something like: params[:user] = {:notification_ids => []} if params[:user].blank? However, its a bit more complicated than this. Since I've got two sets of notifications in two different pages (Page A and Page B).

Comment: This means, if user has notifications checked on the first page. On the second page if user doesn't select any check boxes and form is submitted, then it will set it to none/empty for ALL notifications. Not just for the notifications on the page B (second page), but also for the notifications on the first page.

Comment: If you have half the checkboxes on one page and half on the other and they are using the same param name, then you have a problem (as you mention). You'll have to use two different param names so that one page doesn't erase the other page's checkbox selections. Something like params[:user][:page1_check] and params[:user][:page2_check] and then manually map those to attributes of the user model. Your task will be simple if you put it all on one page.

Answer (score 1):

`check_box_tag` doesn't generate any hidden field. `check_box` does, but looking at your situation, I think using `check_box_tag` is more appropriate since the `check_box` method is mainly used for boolean field. Here is one way to do it.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user[notification_ids][]' %>
<% Notification.all.each do |notification| %>
  <li>
    <%= check_box_tag 'user[notification_ids][]', notification.id, @user.notifications.include?(notification) %>
    <%= label_tag notification.description %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

When the form is submitted with the checkboxes for Notification of id 2 and 3 checked, the value for `params[:user]` is `{ "notification_ids" => ["", "2", "3"] }`. When nothing is checked, `params[:user]` is `{"notification_ids"=>[""]}`, which will clear the user's notifications. This works because [empty string is ignored by ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1530). From here, we can use the usual `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` to update the User model.

Comment: My comment(s) for Georges applies here as well. Kindly look above :-)

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, I have updated my answer to take care of that. A `hidden_field_tag` is added on top to allow the notifications to be cleared.

Comment: Hi Htanata, I tried as you suggested with <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[notification_ids][]' %>. I get the following error: "illegal ObjectId format". I believe its because the form submits it as "user"=>{"notification_ids"=>[""]} instead of "user"=>{"notification_ids"=>[]}. Is there a way to make it submit without the double quotes in [], as such: "user"=>{"notification_ids"=>[]}?

Comment: For example, with <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[notification_ids][]' %>.If user selects one check box. In controller, def update, I have: puts params[:user][:notification_ids].count returns 2. If user does NOT select any check boxes, params[:user][:notification_ids].count returns 1. params[:user][:notification_ids].blank? also returns false

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: As shown in my answer, the empty string is ignored by ActiveRecord, so it's not the problem. I've tested the code and there's no error. Looking at your error message, it's probably a problem with Mongoid. In that case, you'll have to strip the empty string before doing `update_attributes`. For example: `params[:user][:notification_ids] = (params[:user][:notification_ids] || []).reject(&:blank?)`. If you're using this solution, I think you can safely remove the hidden field in the form.

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: Or you might as well use the solution by @Georges.